# ruby and net/http request without content-type

Tags: ruby, apache-tika

I'm trying to make a call to a [Tika server](https://tika.apache.org/) using Net::HTTP::Put. The issue is that the call always passes the `Content-Type`, which keeps Tika from running the detectors (which I want) and then chokes due to the default `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. [Tika docs](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS) suggest to not use that.

So, I have the following:

```
require 'net/http'
port = 9998
host = "localhost"
path = "/meta"

req = Net::HTTP::Put.new(path)
req.body_stream = File.open(file_name)
req['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
req['Accept'] = 'application/json'
response = Net::HTTP.new(host, port).start { |http|
    http.request(req)
}
```

I tried adding `req.delete('content-type')` and setting `initheaders = {}` in various ways, but the default `content-type` keeps getting sent.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated, since I would rather avoid having to make multiple curl calls ... is there any way to suppress the sending of that default header?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `req['Content-Type'] = nil` then Net::HTTP will set it to the default of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', but if you set it to a blank string Net::HTTP leaves it alone:

```
req['Content-Type'] = ''
```

Tika should see that as an invalid type and enable the detectors.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but tika then sees the content type as `*/*` and chokes on unkown type.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Tika will run the detectors if the `Content-Type` is `application/octet-stream`. Adding

```
req.content_type = "application/octet-stream"
```

is now allowing me to get results.